# Deleted files still present in .iml file Include-Resource

Tags: java, intellij-idea, build, osgi

I often have the problem when some java files have been deleted from a project (eigher manually or via version control) there are still references in the project's .iml file.

This leads to an error during the build process (build started in IntelliJ):

```
Error:osgi: [myproject] Input file does not exist: C:/dev/myproject/src/main/java/com/mycompany/myproject/IntentionallyDeletedFile.java
```

Inspecting the .iml file, I can find the reference in:

```
<component name="FacetManager">
    <facet type="Osmorc" name="OSGi">
      <configuration manifestGenerationMode="OsmorcControlled" ...>
        <additionalProperties>
          ...
          <property key="Include-Resource"
```

When I delete it from there manually, the build works again. But I think IntelliJ should be able to handle this automatically.